# How do I add a reference image in Blender 3.6?

Tags: modeling, image

It seems that in the new Blender update, the option to add an image using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is gone, as shown in the screenshot. So how do I add a reference image again?

[image]

Comment: You're in Edit Mode, with a mesh selected. In that case, you will only be offered compatible extensions to your mesh. Do you not get the Empty options from Object Mode? (BTW, you can drag-and-drop an image into a 3D View, for speed)

Comment: @RobinBetts I didn't even realise there was an Image option on the Empty menu! I always use the Images entry which has Reference and Background on it as well as Images as Planes if the addon is enabled. The Empty entry means that you have to go through hoops to actually load an image!

Comment: @JohnEason There I go... clunk, clunk, clunk! :) I do  tend to learn basic internal grammars, and don't bother with convenience functions until I find I really need them. So I go: Oh.. it's an Empty! and have done with it. (I think that's why I don't get on too well with Apple and MS.. too much convenience = too much hidden from me )

Comment: Well... Images is in full view on the top level Shift-A Add menu rather than one down on the Empty one, but each to their own I suppose! :^)

Answer (score 5):

You're in <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode. Go back into <kbd>Object</kbd> mode with <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> and the option should appear.