# Why did Blender remove the "Add Image" option?

Tags: modeling, image, customization

In the top left corner of the viewport, underneath "add" there used to be the option of adding an image (among other options) as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

And now he option has been removed, as seen in this recent screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: You asked that 4 days ago and it was answered then! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299464/how-do-i-add-a-reference-image-in-blender-3-6/299465#299465

Comment: Do not ask questions multiple times, especially not if you already got an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the edit mode of some object.

Switch back to object mode and you will be able to add it. To switch back either click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to open a pie menu OR use the dropdown menu from the header.

Since it's the edit mode of some mesh, you will only be able to add meshes while in the edit mode.

Basically the option is still there, but you are in the wrong mode.

Comment: ...or just hit Tab to toggle between the two modes!